# How to use Custom label in an onClick Javascript button?

Tags: customlabel

Hii I need to use a custom label in my onClick javascript button.

I am getting an error

> Field $Label.Label does not exist. Check spelling.

Though I have already Created the Custom Label

The label I am using is like

> alert('{!$Label.Tax_Code_Input}');

and it should display the word

> GST out 10%

as an alert .Please guide me how to use a custom label in javascript

Comment: This should work.

Comment: There is no issue with this code. make sure your are using  API name of label.

Comment: Please, post your label definition screenshot, together with JS button code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this :

```
alert('{!$Label.Test_CS1}');
```

OR

```
alert('{!JSENCODE($Label.Test_CS1)}');
```

The alert must work

Snap shot of alert :

[image]

Comment: Hii Partha ,Thank you for the answer .It is working this way

Comment: Saswata Das - welcome .. happy to help u :) :)